# Can I create a small easy database in Python?

Tags: python, database

This may sound dumb and pointless but bear with me, I'm a beginner in coding.

I'm developing a project on my own and it requires me to make a small database. I just need user_id, email, points, nº of cards and cards in the table. 
I could just create those as lists and just .append() every time I wanna add something new, right? But how could I access and print those values from several lists, together? Like user_id[0] + email[0] + points [0] or is there an easier way?

Comment: You can create a simple database using sqllite3 in python. Refer the [link](https://github.com/adipandas/python-tutorial-codes/blob/master/DatabaseDemo_crud/src/database_crud.py)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like it's database related (?). Maybe you're thinking of `zip`?

```
names = ["Bob", "Sam", "Jack"]
points = [10, 32, 9000]

for current_name, current_points in zip(names, points):
    print(current_name, current_points)
```

Output:

```
Bob 10
Sam 32
Jack 9000
```